# How many types of UserHandles are there in android?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, multi-user

In my multi user aware application I use the below two ways of obtaining a user handle to OWNER(user 0) user. However both these handles are different. I do not understand why the two user handles are different. Both the code snippets are called from a service class.

1. android.os.Process.myUserHandle()
2. UserHandle.readFromParcel(parcel) from the code below: userId is 0 in my case.

   ```
   public static UserHandle getUserHandle(int userId) {
           Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
           parcel.writeInt(userId);
           parcel.setDataPosition(0);
           UserHandle user = UserHandle.readFromParcel(parcel);
           parcel.recycle();
           return user;
       }
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "different"?

Comment: When I print them in log messages they are not the same value.

Comment: What are you printing? the handle value (int)? The object `toString()`? In Java you compare objects with `equals()`. If you look at the implementation of that in `UserHandle` it compares the integer handle value.